# HTML5 custom data- property. How many per element?

Tags: html

How many custom data tags are allowed per element. Could I have more than one data- property per element? Can I do something like this?

```
<img data-longDescription="This is my really long description that would be longer than this." data-anotherCustomData="Hi Mom" src="mysrc.jpg" alt="my image" />
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have as many `[data-]` attributes as you'd like. What's important is that they don't share the same name, and that they're prefixed with `data-`.

I recommend reviewing [the HTML5 specification](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/global-attributes.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes).

Comment: Thank you.  Couldn't find the specs saying if you could have more than one. Thanks

Comment: It says: "Every HTML element may have any number of custom data attributes specified, with any value."

Answer (score 0):

You can have as many `data-*` attributes as you like, and they can each be as long as you like.